# Converting an ES6 hook based app to Class Based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to convert this piece of code to a Class Based Component. I know I'm going in the reverse direction but I really cant figure out how to do this one. Errors is all I get. Thanks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//Packages
import axios from 'axios';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

const DisplayTable = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


  const getPlayerData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        "https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats"
      );
      console.log(data);
      setPlayers(data.data);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  };


  const columns = [
    { dataField: "name", text:"name" },
    { dataField: "points_per_game", text:"points_per_game" },
    { dataField: "team_name", text:"team_name" },
  ]

  useEffect(()=> {
    getPlayerData();
  }, []);

  return(
  <div>
    <BootstrapTable
      keyField="name"
      data={players}
      columns={columns}
      pagination={paginationFactory()}
    />

  </div>
  )
};

export default DisplayTable;
```

Comment: `Errors is all I get.` What errors specifically, and what's the code that's generating those errors?

Comment: Since you have not mentioned what error you have got. I would outline what needs to be done here. Put your api call in componentDidMount. Once you get the result, set your state there. Remember that setState is asynchronous. So you need to have some sort of loader , flag which checks for data getting fetched and then display the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I've converted your code to Class-Based Component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// packages
import axios from 'axios';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

class DisplayTable extends Component {
  // class constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      players: [],
      loading: false,
    };
  }

  // async all data while component mount
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(
        "https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players-stats"
      );
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({ players: data.data });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  // render starts from here
  render() {
    const { players } = this.state;

    const columns = [
      { dataField: "name", text: "name" },
      { dataField: "points_per_game", text: "points_per_game" },
      { dataField: "team_name", text: "team_name" },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <BootstrapTable
          keyField="name"
          data={players}
          columns={columns}
          pagination={paginationFactory()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayTable;
```

Comment: Thanks Fatema! I figured what I was doing wrong. I had my columns class above my render function. I read more about it now and realised why it was wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to know, you've figured out!